# How to get all-contributers github app to render table of contributors and badge?

Tags: github

I'm using https://github.com/all-contributors/all-contributors, and I've gone through every detail I can on their documentation https://allcontributors.org/ as well.  And been trying different things for the past 2 hours but I can't get this app to render the table of contributors.  Their documentation is incredibly poor.

I have:

```
{
  "files": [
    "readme.md",
    "docs/authors.md",
    "docs/contributors.md"
  ],
  "imageSize": 100,
  "contributorsPerLine": 7,
  "contributorsSortAlphabetically": false,
  "badgeTemplate": "[![All Contributors](https://img.shields.io/badge/all_contributors-<%= contributors.length %>-pink.svg)](#contributors)",
  "contributorTemplate": "<a href=\"<%= contributor.profile %>\"><img src=\"<%= contributor.avatar_url %>\" width=\"<%= options.imageSize %>px;\" alt=\"\"/><br /><sub><b><%= contributor.name %></b></sub></a>",
  "types": {
    "contributor": {
      "symbol": "❤️",
      "description": "Contributor ❤️",
      "link": "[<%= symbol %>](<%= url %> \"<%= description %>\"),"
    }
  },
  "skipCi": true,
  "contributors": [],
  "projectName": ".github",
  "projectOwner": "owner",
  "repoType": "github",
  "repoHost": "https://github.com"
}
```

I then use `@all-contributors add @somename to code` and it does correctly add it to the `.all-contributersrc` file, however it doesn't render the table in the readme.md.

I've also tried to hardcode the list in readme using:

```
<!-- ALL-CONTRIBUTORS-LIST:START -->

<!-- ALL-CONTRIBUTORS-LIST:END -->
```

But no luck, nothing happens.

I also can not get the badge working.  I can hardcode the badge and display "a" badge, but it never uses the above template badge with dynamic contributor length.  So it's also not injecting the badge or using that template badge at all.

How can I get this bot to correctly show the badge and show the contributor list and generate the table in readme.md?

Note: I'm not interested in using node or running some generate command manually locally, then it defeats the point of using that app at all, then I can just as well do it myself.  According to their documentation it should be generating the table automatically on first contributor, but it does not.

Also when I go to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/all-contributors/all-contributors/master/README.md in raw view, I can see:

[image]

Which tells me it has to be generating that table somehow, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and emulate [other repositories using the same bot](https://github.com/search?q=contributorsSortAlphabetically&type=code), like:

- [`AtlasFoundation/AvatarCreator`](https://github.com/AtlasFoundation/AvatarCreator) with [this commit](https://github.com/AtlasFoundation/AvatarCreator/commit/74ec6a6184dbfb95a3dcd2b75c5392d81d6786ff).
- [`mrz1836/go-nownodes`](https://github.com/mrz1836/go-nownodes) and its own [`.all-contributorsrc`](https://github.com/mrz1836/go-nownodes/blob/0e2c0538d1b11b59666e396e561568a3e5edce8c/.all-contributorsrc) file

As an alternative, the [`estruyf/vscode-front-matter`](https://github.com/estruyf/vscode-front-matter) does include its own contributor list, using [this commit](https://github.com/estruyf/vscode-front-matter/commit/e02a766070dc33a8dacc23bd7ef7c7092dc5d822) which calls [`contrib.rocks`](https://contrib.rocks/preview).

Comment: Thank you @VonC.  But I don't think this helps me.  That commit, https://github.com/AtlasFoundation/AvatarCreator/commit/74ec6a6184dbfb95a3dcd2b75c5392d81d6786ff, is the commit made by the bot, that's what the bot is supposed to commit, but when I do it the bot is never making that commit.  It should be injecting that table, same as in the above commit, but it doesn't.  My setup with the RC file is the same as theirs and also as the official repo's, but there something that makes the bot never make that table commit on the first commit.

Comment: The CMS solution is also not really a solution, running a full cms in vscode is to me just silly.  It will lock me down to vscode and force me to use that, even if I'm using another language like rust and using a full blown cms just for a contributor list isn't a solution.  Not to mention how it will cripple your use of scss/code splitting/bundling/react/prod optimizations/client side caching, it's just sily to run a cms like that unless you can't dev at all and it's your only solution.  I appreciate it anyways.

Comment: I've ended up using `![Contributors](https://contrib.rocks/image?repo=name/.github)`, which doesn't allow you to add i.e. a project manager or something who also contributed to the project in others ways, but it at least works for now.  In the all-contributors slack they are also unresponsive and don't answer you for over 24 hours now so I won't continue to support them.

Comment: @Matriarx I understand. At least, you have an alternative, even if it is not as complete as `all-contributors`.

Comment: yes! you are right.  I was thinking I'm going to look into how much work it is to build a bot like this, for automatic external contributor list (like design or project management or advice etc included), and also for semantic/conventional commit changelog/release generation.  The existing apps for that is pretty poor or unmaintained and I can imagine many people are looking for those. Then I can use it myself as well.  But I've never used the github api so good luck to me.